# Is there a way to identify a Kotlin data class from a regular Kotlin class?

Tags: reflection, metaprogramming, kotlin, data-class

Is there a way to identify a Kotlin data class from a regular Kotlin class? Like using reflection maybe?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since 1.1 there is an isData property on the class

```
MyDataClass::class.isData
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Kotlin 1.1 use `isData` property on `KClass`. ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-data.html))

Before Kotlin 1.1 you can try to use some heuristics, like check that it contains next methods:

- `public final copy`
- `public final component{N}`
- `public static copy$default`

Note these implementation details could be changed in the future.