# Is there a way to require a generic type to be a data class in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, data-class

The following does not work, but hopefully helps you understand what I mean:

```
class Example<T : DataClass>
```

In case you would like to know what I am trying to accomplish, this is an example of what I had in mind:

```
class Repository<T> where T : Entity, // Entity defines mutable property 'id'
                          T : DataClass {

  // assume there is a map here

  fun add(obj: T) {
    val copy = obj.copy(id = generateID())
    map.put(copy.id, copy)
  }

}
```

Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have the feeling that what you actually want is that T should be able to copy itself with a new ID, and have an ID. Not necessarily that it is a data class. So you could just use an interface to define that.

For example:

```
interface CopyableWithId<out T> where T: CopyableWithId<T> {
    fun copy(newId: Long): T
    val id: Long
}

data class BarBaz(override var id: Long, var name: String): CopyableWithId<BarBaz> {
    override fun copy(newId: Long): BarBaz = copy(id = newId)
}

class Repository<T> where T : CopyableWithId<T>{

    val map: MutableMap<Long, CopyableWithId<T>> = HashMap()

    fun add(obj: T) {
        val copy = obj.copy(generateID())
        map.put(copy.id, copy)
    }

    private fun generateID(): Long {
        return 1L
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a concern about this causing an infinite loop? Where we can't really call `super.copy`, won't it call copy recursively? I named mine `copyID` just to be sure.

Comment: It's working. copy coming from data class. copy name can be clone or another.

Answer (score 6):

No, `data` classes don't have any specific representation in type system and cannot be distinguished from regular classes ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069988/is-there-a-way-to-identify-a-kotlin-data-class-from-a-regular-kotlin-class)).

You can, however, require the methods a `data` class with certain number of components has using an interface (actually it will be a marker interface on `data` classes).

Here's an example for `data` classes with two components:

```
interface Data2<T1, T2> {
    operator fun component1(): T1
    operator fun component2(): T2
    fun copy(t1: T1, t2: T2): Data2<T1, T2>
}
```

<sup>`toString`, `hashCode` and `equals` can be called on any type anyway.</sup>

Then just mark your `data` class with the interface:

```
data class Impl(val i: Int, val s: String): Data2<Int, String>

val d: Data2<Int, String> = Impl(1, "2")
val (c1, c2) = d
val copy = d.copy(-1, d.component2())
```

`copy` function is not completely type-safe because Kotlin [doesn't have self type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565043/how-to-specify-own-type-as-return-type-in-kotlin) (and no way to require interface implementations to be subtype of a specific type), but if you only mark your `data` classes with it, it should work (see another option below).

Another drawback is that you lose default parameters of `copy` method and have to call it with all the parameters specified:

```
val d = myD2.copy(newValue, myD2.component2())
```

---

<sup>Another option is to define these interfaces as `Data2<T1, T2, out Self>`, `class Impl(...): Data2<..., Impl>`, and make `copy` return `Self`, but it won't make it any better if you use the interface as `Data2<SomeType, SomeType, *>`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You also can implement copy or component1, component2 more generalised way.

For example:

```
    interface Copyable <T> {
        fun copy(fields: T.() -> T): T
    }

    data class BarBaz(var id: Long, var name: String): Copyable<BarBaz> {
        override fun copy(fields: BarBaz.() -> BarBaz): BarBaz {
           val instance = fields(this)
           return copy(id = instance.id, name = instance.name)
        }
    }

class Repository<T> where T : Copyable<T>{

    val map: MutableMap<Long, Copyable<T>> = HashMap()

    fun add(obj: T) {
        val copy = obj.copy{id = generateID()}
        map.put(copy.id, copy)
    }

    private fun generateID(): Long {
        return 1L
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great but doesn't work. Inside method `add` you don't have knowledge about `BarBaz` so you don't have knowledge of field `id`. You can add that knowledge to `Copyable` but it won't change much, you still won't be able to construct copy inside `copy` lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Could be unrelated because I had similar but slightly different problem.

I need to have moved shared logic to a super class and the issue was that I can't use **copy** method of generic **T**. I found this workaround:

Entity:

```
data class MyEntity(
    val id: String,
    val createdAt: Instant,
    val updatedAt: Instant
)
```

Abstract Generic Repository:

```
abstract class GenericRepository<T> {

    abstract val copyFn: KCallable<T>

    fun add(obj: T) {
        val instanceParameter = copyFn.instanceParameter!!
        val idParameter = copyFn.findParameterByName("id")!!
        val copy = copyFn.callBy(
            mapOf(
                instanceParameter to obj,
                idParameter to "new id"
            )
        )
        // Do whatever you want with the copy
    }
}
```

Or cleaner and more generic version of Abstract Generic Repository:

```
abstract class BetterGenericRepository<T> {

    abstract val copyFn: KCallable<T>

    fun add(obj: T): T {
        val instanceParameter = getInstanceParameter()
        val idParameter = getParameterByName(instanceParameter, "id")
        val updatedAtParameter = getParameterByName(instanceParameter, "updatedAt")
        val copy = copyFn.callBy(
            mapOf(
                instanceParameter to obj,
                idParameter to "new id",
                updatedAtParameter to Instant.now()
            )
        )
        // Do whatever you want with the copy
        return copy
    }

    private fun getInstanceParameter() =
        copyFn.instanceParameter
            ?: throw RuntimeException("${copyFn.returnType} must be Data Class or its method '${copyFn.name}' must have 'instanceParameter' as KParameter")

    private fun getParameterByName(instanceParameter: KParameter, name: String) =
        copyFn.findParameterByName(name)
            ?: throw RuntimeException("${instanceParameter.type} must have '$name' property")
}
```

Specific implementation of Abstract Repository

```
class MyRepository: BetterGenericRepository<MyEntity>() {
    override val copyFn = MyEntity::copy
}
```

And simple check:

```
fun main() {
    val repository = MyRepository()
    val entity = MyEntity(
        id = "1",
        createdAt = Instant.EPOCH,
        updatedAt = Instant.EPOCH
    )
    println(entity)
    println(repository.add(entity))
}
```

The result

```
MyEntity(id=1, createdAt=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, updatedAt=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)
MyEntity(id=new id, createdAt=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, updatedAt=2020-08-26T13:29:42.982Z)
```